# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream. ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpclient, .net-core-3.1

I am using following code to call some http api's

```
public static async Task<GenerricApiResponse> ProcessWebRequest<T>(string url, T req,ILog Logger, int timeoutInSeconds = 0)
    {
        var obj = new GenerricApiResponse();
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var jsonRequest = JsonSerializer.Serialize(req);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
                var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest);
                content.Headers.Clear();
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
                {
                    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeoutInSeconds);
                }
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);                    
                obj.HttpResponseCode = response.StatusCode;

                try
                {
                    string responsecontent = null;
                    responsecontent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    if (response.Content != null && response.Content.Headers != null)
                    {
                        obj.ResponseContentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
                        if (responsecontent != null && obj.ResponseContentType == "text/html")
                        {
                            if (responsecontent != null && responsecontent.Length > 1000)
                            {
                                responsecontent = responsecontent.Substring(0, 1000) + "...";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    obj.Response = responsecontent;
                }
                catch
                {
                    obj.IsError = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            if (ex.InnerException is TimeoutException)
            {
                ex = ex.InnerException;
            }

            obj.IsError = true;
            obj.Exception = ex;
            obj.Response = ex.Message;                
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

But getting error

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.  ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.

Any idea what is missing in my code or what wrong i am doing?

Still getting it. Even i have passed 90 seconds as timeout but no effect.
Strange thing is some time it did work

Comment: does this happen when the method is only called once, or if you have multiple calls to it?. If it is the second it might be possible that you just run out of available sockets for the clients. That's why a httpClient should be a singleton which gets injected

Comment: Same method call to some other api and it works. looks like there is problem in response.

Comment: and the response of the request is not chunked right? Because you add it to the request header but  do you validate that the server is respecting that?

Comment: please suggest what correction needed

Comment: Perhaps try altering the code to match the pattern described here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests you can also remove the 'using' block

Answer (score 0):

I also get this exception. after investigation, by default HttpClient wait response header + content ready for all methods, eg. PostAsync, SendAsync, GetAsync. so if response has no/invalid content-length. you will get this error. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590012/net-httpclient-accept-partial-response-when-response-header-has-an-incorrect). so it is recommend to use SendAsync(xxx, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)

```
    using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
    {
        var body = File.ReadAllText("body.txt").Trim();

        req.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");

        // the follow code throw exception
        // System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely
        // since 'HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead' is the default behavior
        // var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(req, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(req, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
```

Comment: if want to read response content for wrong content-length, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590012/net-httpclient-accept-partial-response-when-response-header-has-an-incorrect

Comment: PostAsync and GetAsync they are use SendAsync in Background